# Which is the best way to sync Core Data to Dropbox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, dropbox-api

I am new in sync. I want to sync my iOS application core data to dropbox. I search google about this. I got two types of API's in DropBox. One is Sync API and another one is Core API. I don't know which one is the best for my requirement.

Please suggest me the right path. Thanks in advance.

FYI

[Sync API reference link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios)

[Core API reference link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios)

Comment: What do you mean with syncing Core Data to Dropbox? Please clarify your goal?

Comment: I am doing finance application. I store the each transaction in CoreData. Now i need to sync this transactions to other devices using DropBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment you should clarify what you mean with *sync Core Data to Dropbox*.

Sync is a quite complex arguments.

If your goal is to store the entire persistent store file (e.g. sqlite store) in Dropbox Sync Api is the way. You can save the file through API. BUT be aware that the store could corrupt, so avoid it. It's a bad idea to share the store file across multiple users.

If you need to sync data across multiple devices (and not files) Dropbox does not provide this functionality. By the way [Ensembles Framework](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles) by Drew McCormack provides a way to sync Core Data apps through Droppox, iCloud, etc..

Otherwise you have different options: 1) use iCloud as is, 2) set up your server with your own API to sync data (http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) or 3) use ready backend services like [Parse](https://parse.com) or [BaasBox](http://www.baasbox.com). The former is a service where data are stored in Parse servers while the latter can be used with your own server...

Comment: I need to sync data across multiple devices. I am not clear with DropBox Sync API. So i thought this API given direct functionality to sync core data to DropBox like iCloud sync.

Comment: If you save the persistent store file on Dropbox, you're pretty much guaranteed to corrupt the file before long. Neither Core Data nor SQLite reacts well to that kind of sync scenario.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yep!! I agree with you..I will modify my answer according to your comment...I expressed myself in the wrong manner...

Answer (score 0):

FYI Dropbox deprecated Sync API and Datastore API in April 2015.  It wants you to use its main and only Core API V2. https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/